# Variadic function treats const char* as char const(&)[len]

Tags: c++, optimization, clang++

The following code generates the function `log` twice:

```cc
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void log(Args && ...args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args);
    (std::cout << std::endl);
}

int main() {
    log("Testing ", " my ", "log");
    log("log ", " appears ", " twice :(");
    return 0;
}
```

Output from `nm`:

```
$ nm -a test | grep log | c++filt
0000000100001160 T void log<char const (&) [5], char const (&) [10], char const (&) [10]>(char const (&) [5], char const (&) [10], char const (&) [10])
0000000100001100 T void log<char const (&) [9], char const (&) [5], char const (&) [4]>(char const (&) [9], char const (&) [5], char const (&) [4])
```

Is there a way to get `log` to treat strings just as `const char*` or in any other type that won't cause it to be generated in the binary for every call? it's not a big deal when it comes to a small function that doesn't do match, but obviously when more features are needed from a logging module, it becomes heavier, and I don't want that function to be generated for every log call.

Comment: What language are you using? Your tag says C++ but C++ doesn’t have an `#import` directive.

Comment: I'm using C++17. I never gave it a thought, but on clang it just works. I'll edit back to `#include` to avoid confusion.

Comment: The reason for this, is that you use a forwarding reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). Therefore the type is deduced exactly and does not decay. Removing the `&&` would likely work but maybe is not wanted.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you can try creating a forcedly inlined wrapper and cast arguments to `std::decay`-ed types. Hopefully if the wrapper is inlined, compiler won't generate symbols.

Comment: MSVC and GCC linkers can fold identical function bodies. Does clang support `-fipa-icf`?

Comment: I guess not ```clang: error: unknown argument: '-fipa-icf'```